# jQuery variable in handler

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jQuery and am making a history API-ish script in jQuery so only the needed info in a new page loads on a click. The problem is I don't know how to place the var in the handler, atleast I think its called the handler. It will definitely be a simple thing.

```
 $("a#click").click(function() {
 var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");

  $("#main").load("addressValue #load");

 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use:

```
 $("a#click").click(function() {
 var addressValue = this.href;

  $("#main").load(addressValue + " #load");

 return false;
});
```

It should work; the problem was that you were placing the variable into the string, so it was being evaluated as the variable-name, not the variable concatenated with the `' #load'` string.

Also, for the `href` it's slightly faster to avoid invoking jQuery, and just use the native DOM approach (it's a micro optimisation, but it's just slightly cheaper).

It's worth noting that `this.href` does (sometimes-problematically) retrieve the absolute path implied by whatever value is, strictly speaking, inside of the `href` attribute, including the domain. Whereas the jQuery approach simply retrieves whatever is in the attribute, so:

```
<a href="/help/contact.html">contact page</a>:
this.href            : "http://subdomain.example.com/help/contact.html"
$(this).attr('href') : "/help/contact.html"
```

Comment: Both correct, thanks. I shall have to accept @adeneo answer as he got it just before you

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped, even if he helped faster... =)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I will have a look into a DOM approach but i just love jQuery!

Comment: It's usually not a problem, but `this.href` will get you the entire href, including the domain, while jQuery gets the attribute the way it is written in the HTML, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVfWy/), could be a problem depending on the adress specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a#click").on('click', function() {
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#main").load(addressValue+" #load");
    return false;
});
```